# Point Order on Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

i got stuck doing the exercise 4.5 d) in the Book [Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography](http://koclab.cs.ucsb.edu/teaching/ecc/eccPapers/Washington-ch04.pdf) by L. Washington and would be grateful for hints.

> Let $ p \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 4)}$ be prime and let $E$ be given by $y^2 = x^3 -kx$, where $k \not\equiv 0 \text{ (mod $p$)}$.
> Let $k$ be a square but not a fourth power mod $p$. Show that exactly one of the curves $y^2 = x^3 -x$ and $y^2 = x^3 -kx$ has a point of order $4$ defined over $\mathbf{F_p}$.

I tried to find a point such that $2P = (\pm\sqrt{k},0)$, but that did not work out and solving the division polynomial $\psi_4$ also didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $k=d^2$ then $y^2=x^3-kx$ is isomorphic to $E_d:y^2=d(x^3-x)$.
- $E_1:y^2=x^3-x$.
- Since $d$ is not a square, for all $a\in \Bbb{F}_p$, either $(a,\pm \sqrt{a^3-a})\in E_1(\Bbb{F}_p)$ or $(a,\pm \sqrt{d(a^3-a)})\in E_d(\Bbb{F}_p)$
- $\#E_1(\Bbb{F}_p)+\#E_d(\Bbb{F}_p)= 2(p-3)+8\equiv 4\bmod 8$
- Both $E_1(\Bbb{F}_p)$ and $E_d(\Bbb{F}_p)$ contain the 2-torsion (the points coming from $a=\infty$ or $a^3-a=0$)
- Thus, exactly one of $\# E_1(\Bbb{F}_p)$,$\# E_d(\Bbb{F}_p)$ is $\equiv 0\bmod 8$, the other is $\equiv 4\bmod 8$.
- Exactly one of $ E_1(\Bbb{F}_p)$,$E_d(\Bbb{F}_p)$ contains some point of order $4$.

Comment: Thank you for providing hints, i have a problem getting from the second to last bullet point to the conclusion that exactly one of the elliptic curves contains some point of order 4. Can you explain it in more detail please.

Comment: Is $2(p-3)+8$ clear to you?

Comment: yes, since d is not a square mod p and $E_d$ is a twist of $E_1$ we have that $ \#E_1(\mathbf{F}_p) + \#E_d(\mathbf{F}_p) = p +1 - a + p +1 +a = 2p+2 $ and since $p\equiv 1$(mod 4) we got $2(4r +1) +2 = 8r +4 \equiv 4$ mod 8.

Comment: $E_1(F_p)$ is a group so the size of the 2-torsion $\# E_1(F_p)[2]=4$ divides $\# E_1(F_p)$ and it contains some point of order 4 iff $\# E_1(F_p)[4]> \# E_1(F_p)[2]$ iff $8 \ | \ \# E_1(F_p)[4]\ | \ \# E_1(F_p)$

Comment: $2(p-3)+8$ follows from that $p-3 $ is the number of $ a$ such that $a^3-a\ne 0$, multiplied by 2 for the sign of $\sqrt{a^3-a}$, and $8=2.4$ is the 2-torsion $(a\in 0,-1,1,\infty$) counted two times since it is in both $E_1(F_p)$ and $E_d(F_p)$.

Comment: I can now follow your argument why exactly one of them has to have a point of order 4. Regarding the number of points in $\#E_1(F_p)+\#E_d(F_p)$ the argument why every $a$ that fulfills $a³-a \neq 0$ is counted would be: Since $d^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1$ and for either possible value of $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv \pm 1$ we have that it is either contained in $E_1$ or $E_d$. Is the argument i made before wrong or did you wanted to show another possible derivation?

Comment: There is only one derivation, the one I showed: if $a^3-a\ne 0$ then exactly one of $a^3-a,d(a^3-a)$ is a square. What do you not understand for the point of order $4$?