Points of order 4 in $E(\mathbf{F}_p)$ where $E: y^2 = x^3 -x$
I was playing around with sage trying to find some clues for how to answer a question [1] and I found that for all primes $\le 10000$, if there exists a $k \in \mathbf{F}_p$ that is a square but not a fourth power then:

$E(\mathbf{F}_p)$ always has points of order 4 when $E: y^2=x^3 -x$
$E(\mathbf{F}_p)$ never has points of order 4 when $E: y^2=x^3 -kx$ where $k$ is a square but not a fourth power in $\mathbf{F}_p$
$E_1(\mathbf{F}_p) \cong E_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ where $E_1: y^2=x^3 -k_1x$, $E_2: y^2=x^3 -k_2x$ and $k_i$ are squares but not fourth powers in $\mathbf{F}_p$

I was wondering if this was true $\forall p$. If I can solve the question [1] then we would have #1 $\iff$ #2. From Theorem 4.23 we know that $|E_1(\mathbf{F}_p)| = |E_2(\mathbf{F}_p)|$, but this does not imply that the groups are isomorphic [I think] since the j-invariants are different.
Any advice on how to answer the question [1] or prove/disprove the above 1-3?

[1] exercise 4.5 (part 4) on p115 of Elliptic Curves Number Theory And Cryptography (2nd Edition)
Let $p = 1 \pmod 4$ be prime and let $E$ be given by $y^2 = x^3 - kx$, where $k \neq 0 \pmod p$.

[DONE] Use Theorem 4.23 to show that $|E(\mathbf{F}_p)|$ is a multiple of 4 when $k$ is a square mod $p$.
[DONE] Show that when $k$ is a square mod $p$, then $E(\mathbf{F}_p)$ contains 4 points $P$ satisfying $2P = \infty$. Conclude again that $|E(\mathbf{F}_p)|$ is a multiple of 4.
[DONE] Show that when $k$ is not a square mod $p$, then $E(\mathbf{F}_p)$ contains no points of order 4.
[WIP] Let $k$ be a square but not a fourth power mod $p$. Show that exactly one of the curves $y^2 = x^3 - x$ and $y^2 = x^3 - kx$ has a point of order 4 defined over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

[2] Theorem 4.23
Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $k \neq 0 \pmod p$. Let $N_p =| E(\mathbf{F}_p)|$, where $E$ is the elliptic curve
$$y^2 = x^3 - kx$$

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $N_p = p + 1$.
If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, write $p = a^2 + b^2$, where $a,b$ are integers with $b$ even and $a + b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Then

$$
N_p = \begin{cases} 
p + 1 - 2a & \text{ if $k$ is a fourth power mod $p$} \\ 
p + 1 + 2a & \text{ if $k$ is a square mod $p$ but not a 4th power mod $p$} \\
p + 1 \pm 2b & \text{ if $k$ is not a square mod $p$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Are you sure about (1)? What about $p=11$?

For $p=11$ you are right, there are no points of order 4. I need to adjust the context: only look at $p$ where there exist elements of $F_p$ that are squares but not fourth powers. The squares in $F_{11}$ are all fourth powers

Equivalently, you want to restrict to $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then.

Would you mind explaining why those are equivalent? Or could you give me a clue to try and figure it out myself?

Re my previous comment, recall that $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$. For 3), the same remark implies that you can  write $k_2=u^4k_1$ and then there is an explicit bijection between $E_1(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $E_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

I can't figure out the equivalence. I tried the following: look at the size of the image of the map $x^n$ for $n=2,4$. If the images of the 2 maps are the same size then there all squares are fourth powers. For $n=2$ the kernel is size 2 since $x^2-1$ splits in every field, so the image is size $(p-1)/2$. For $n=4$ the kernel is either size 2 or 4, depending on whether $x^2+1$ splits in the field or not, which depends on whether $x^2 \equiv p-1 (\text{mod } p)$. But I can't relate this to $p \equiv 1 (\text{mod } 4)$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For the original question in the textbook there is this already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993764/point-order-on-elliptic-curve?rq=1
